# Using the Map datatype in Cassandra (or not)

Tags: java, cassandra

I will be saving a flattened JSON entity type into Cassandra. I have 2 options for the data model:

```
((entityType, entityId), jsonPath), value
```

OR

```
(entityType, entityId), map<text, text> keyValue
```

My use case would be, when inserting for each entityId - delete all mappings and insert. And query by entityType, entityId and jsonPath.

Which of the above should be better performing/scalable from a *streaming-ingestion-and-UI-query* system perspective?

A flattened JSON will have around ~100 fields. Number of entities would be less than a million - in mid hundreds of thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to what Erick said, large collections in Cassandra can lead to other issues.  DataStax has some documentation on how to "[freeze](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_using/refCollectionType.html)" collections to help with different access patterns.  The tradeoff, is that non-frozen collections can generate a LOT of tombstones during various high write throughput scenarios, and frozen collections must re-write the entire collection on an in-place write.

**tl;dr;**

Mapping to individual columns is a *much* better option.

Answer (score 3):

Wherever possible, you will be better off mapping the fields to CQL columns instead of a `map` collection.

Working with CQL columns equates to simpler CRUD operations. Cheers!